# How to call Action method from aspx page using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to call action method from aspx page using ajax as per below code:

```
var authHeader = window.btoa("Ankita:Ankita");
  $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: 'http://localhost:52099/Home',
                        async: false,
                        headers: { Authorization: authHeader },
                        success: function (response) {
                            alert("hi");
                        },
                        error: function(e){
                            alert(e);
                        }
                    });
```

But it is not working, What I made wrong here?

**Moreover, I want to display return view page as a popup within aspx. How can I achieve it?**

Thanks!

Comment: `http://localhost:52099/Home` you have in link only the controller name. Add action name in url for example `http://localhost:52099/Home/Index/`. Check that is your **action** method have **HttpGet** attribute becouse you request is POST type.

Comment: Why are you adding so many options, specially the "async:false" statement? That will render the entire page useless until it completes and will look like the browser is frozen up to the user.  When programming, you should follow the KISS(Keep It Simple Stupid) rule. Pass only what you need to pass.

Comment: @DawidWekwejt,  I have a hunch the "ASPX" is going to be WebForms unless they are rocking a very old version of MVC.

Comment: @DawidWekwejt: Index is my default method so I did not have mention it.

Comment: I have mention HTTPGET to my method and URL like: http://localhost:52099/Medication/Index still not working. One more thing this ajax call is the success part of another ajax call

Comment: Why did you set `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`, when you don't send any data in `$.ajax({ ..., data: ... }); ?`

Comment: Even if when I am passing data it is not working.

Comment: When you ask something to someone where people cannot see your screen then *But Its not working* should be definable. What's not working ? does your computer crash?? please make it clear. how you've setup your project. are both projects *(mvc and web from)* under a single solution?

Comment: Why do you need to call action method from aspx page? Do you get any console error?

Answer (score 0):

In this block here:

```
 success: function (response) {
                            alert("hi");
                        },
```

The response is the returned view, so what you want to do is find the body of your popup. I am assuming its a bootstrap modal, and replace the inner html with it. And then pop it up.

```
 success: function (response) {
                            $("#popupdivmodal").find('div.body').html('').html(response);
                        },
```